# Convert JSON string to HashMap in Java

Tags: json

How can I convert JSON string to HashMap. My JSON string is like

```
{
  "AvailableDeliveries": {
    "500": {
      "code": "INOFFICE",
      "desc": "In Office",
      "id": 500,
      "name": "IN OFFICE"
     },
    "502": {
      "code": "TELEPHONE",
      "desc": "Telephone",
      "id": 502,
      "name": "TELEPHONE"
    },
    "503": {
      "code": "DIY DOC ACCESS",
      "desc": "Online Documents",
      "id": 503,
      "name": "DIY DOC ACCESS"
    }
  }
}
```

I looked on other examples which have collection of object but I have this extra top level object "AvailableDeliveries" not sure how to handle that level.

Comment: did you tried with objectmapper

Answer (score 0):

import jackson-all-1.8.2.jar 
create a mapper for the object mapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

create a hashmap

```
map = objectMapper.readValue( json, HashMap.class );
```

Hope this will work